# Need to open 'this' tooltip

Tags: jquery, this

I have this script to add a close button to my tooltip but my problem is that as I have 2 tooltips I need to add a 'open this tooltip' but I don't know where, can someone help me please.

```
var $t = $('.by-click').tooltipster({
    trigger: 'custom',
    timer: 0,
    functionReady: function(origin, tooltip) {
        tooltip.find('.tooltipster-content').css('pointer-events', 'auto')
        .on('mouseleave.tooltipster', function(e) {
                e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        })
        .find('.close-tlp')
        .on('click', function(e) {
                origin.tooltipster('hide');
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    }
});

$('.by-click').on('click', function(e) {

    $t.tooltipster('show');

});
```

Comment: here's a demo : http://jsfiddle.net/jKwZ6/19/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Id of an element must be unique, so change the id of `button` to class attribute

```
<button class="btn">Click me!</button>
```

then in the button click handler fine the previous element which is the element in which the `tooltip` is initialized and then show it

```
$('.btn').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).prev().tooltipster('show');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yH8t6/)

Answer (score 0):

You are way better off using event delegation for these things. Compare:

```
$(document)
.on('mouseleave.tooltipster', function (e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
})
.on('click', '.tooltipster-show', function (e) {
    $(this).parent().find('.tooltipster').tooltipster('show');
})
.on('click', '.tooltipster-hide', function (e) {
    $(this).closest(".tooltipster-base").data("origin").tooltipster('hide');
});

$('.tooltipster').tooltipster({ trigger: 'custom', timer: 0 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jKwZ6/20/